# Deleted /Library/Python folder. Is it possible restore?

Tags: python

I am on Mac OS X 10.7.2.
I deleted old python library folder before upgrading to newer python.
[But I found later that I should never delete the factory-shipped python.](http://docs.python.org/using/mac.html)

> The Apple-provided build of Python is installed in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework and /usr/bin/python, respectively. You should never modify or delete these, as they are Apple-controlled and are used by Apple- or third-party software.

Is there a way to restore what I deleted in the folder?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? That doesn't require a backup and doesn't require another mac running the same version as yours?

Comment: It's been so long that i don't remember what kind of fix i might have had.

Comment: I deleted the system python long time ago without thinking about the consequences. So far no problems at all... except for iPhoto no longer works. I just realized it is because of Python 2.6 missing. I don't have a good backup and I don't have where to get the system python from. Any tips or ideas how to restore it without having to reinstall OS X are much appreciated

Comment: I would try installing python using homebrew

Comment: I've done it already and I still get the same error. Here is the output when i try to start iPhoto from terminal http://pastebin.com/Dt4t0G9W

Comment: Just copied `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` from another computer and everything works fine again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you may either restore from your Time Machine backup, or copy it back from another Mac running the same 10.7.2

Comment: while this solves the specific problem for the person that asked the question. The general requirement of another mac running the same version being available (and having a pristine copy) is not a good solution. Apple should have a way to do this.

Comment: Copying from another computer `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

`/Library/Python` is empty in a new installation.

Comment: On Lion, Python 2.7 Library is under /Library/Python I think.

Comment: Everything you install via `easy_install` or `pip` will go there. The Python standard library is in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7`.

Comment: System relevant data (such as the Python standard library) is almost never stored in `/Library/`. `/Library` is for user-installed additional stuff.